# Как собрать слайдер, который будет перемещать иконки по кривой?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, slider

Хочу попробовать себя в вёрстке сайтов. Нашел интересный макет: https://www.behance.net/gallery/72919739/Educational-digital-project-about-Renaissance-Era
Меня заинтересовала кривая с иконками (в приложении выделена зеленым цветом), как я понимаю иконки, это ссылки на страницы.
Как считаете можно как-то сделать похожий слайдер? Я не знаю js. Может есть какие-нибудь готовые решения? Буду благодарен за любую полезную информацию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну как вариант

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 8 4'%3E%3Cpath d='M0 1C2 1 2 3 4 3C6 3 6 1 8 1' stroke='%23FF0000' stroke-width='0.1' fill='none'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") repeat-x left center / calc(100% / 2.85) auto;
}

.list .item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.list .item:nth-child(odd) {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.list .item:nth-child(odd) .avatar {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.list .item:nth-child(even) {
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.list .item:nth-child(even) .avatar {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.list .item .avatar {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: green;
}

.list .item .name {
  width: 50px;
  height: 1em;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="avatar"></div>
    <div class="name"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="avatar"></div>
    <div class="name"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="avatar"></div>
    <div class="name"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="avatar"></div>
    <div class="name"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="avatar"></div>
    <div class="name"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="avatar"></div>
    <div class="name"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!

Comment: @КириллБоровой, не за что)